# Finding the theta bounds for integration of a problem (double integration)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to convert this double integral with rectangular coordinates to polar coordinates. The double integral in question: $$\int_{-\sqrt2}^{-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}{\int_{-x}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+3}}\space dydx$$

What I have solved so far:
Bounds are y=-x, y=$\sqrt{4-x^2}, x=-\sqrt2, x=\frac{-\sqrt2}{2}$. The graph is a semicircle above the x-axis, centered at the origin, with the line y=-x passing through.

My r=[$\frac{\sqrt2}{2},2$] and $\theta=[n/a,\frac{3\pi}{4}]$.

That makes my integral with double coordinates as $$\int_{n/a}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}{\int_{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}^{2}2r\sqrt{r^2+3}}\space drd\theta$$

I am unsure as to how to solve the lower bounds of integration for $d\theta$, marked as n/a. I have tried equating $y=-x \space and \space y=\sqrt{4-x^2}\space $ but I do not know if that is the right solution to this. I hope to get some help. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you draw the region you should see that in polar coordinates the bounds of $r$ changes with $\theta$. The bounds you've found for $r$ cannot be right.

Answer (score 1):

The shaded part in the diagram is the region for your integral.

[image]

The lower bound of $y$ is line $y = - x$ and the upper bound is $y = \sqrt{4-x^2} \implies x^2 + y^2 = 4$ which is a circle of radius $2$. Now looking at bounds of $x$,

$ \displaystyle x = r \cos\theta = - \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \implies r = - \frac{\sec \theta}{\sqrt2}$

At the intersection of line $x = r\cos\theta = - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and circle $r = 2$, $\theta = \arccos(- \frac{1}{2\sqrt2})$

The line $y = -x \implies \tan\theta = -1$ or $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

So the integral should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_{\arccos(- 1/ (2\sqrt2))}^{3\pi/4} \int_{-\sec\theta/\sqrt2}^{2} 2r \sqrt{r^2+3} ~ dr ~ d\theta$